# A closed subspace generated by open $F_{\sigma}$ sets of $K$ in $C(K)^{**}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space. For a bounded Borel measurable function $f$ on $K$, we define $\phi_{f}\in C(K)^{**}$ by $\phi_{f}(\mu)=\int_{K}fd\mu$ for all $\mu\in C(K)^{*}$. It is easy to see that $\|\phi_{f}\|=\|f\|_{\infty}$. Thus the space of all bounded Borel measurable functions on $K$ can be considered as a closed subspace of $C(K)^{**}$. We let $Z$ be the norm closed subspace of $C(K)^{**}$ generated by $\{\chi_{U}:U$ open $F_{\sigma}$ sets in $K\}$. Given a sequence $(U_{n})_{n}$ of disjoint open $F_{\sigma}$ sets in $K$ and a bounded scalar sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$, we define $g(t)=a_{n}$ for $t\in U_{n}$ and $g(t)=0$ for $t\notin \cup_{n}U_{n}.$ Then $g$ is a bounded Borel measurable function. It seems clear that $g$ belongs to $Z$. But I am not sure.

Question. Does $g$ belong to $Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $a_n$ is a bounded sequence,  by compactness we can find a finite set of scalars $b_1, \dots, b_m$ such that for every $a_n$ there exists a $b_{k_n}$ with $|a_n - b_{k_n}| \le \epsilon$.  Now consider the function $h = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{k_n} \chi_{U_n}$, that is, $h(t) = b_{k_n}$ for $t \in U_n$.  Clearly $\|\phi_g - \phi_h\| = \|g-h\|_{\infty} \le \epsilon$.  Now set $V_k = \bigcup_{k_n = k} U_n$.  Then $V_k$ is an open $F_\sigma$ since it is a countable union of open $F_\sigma$s, and we can write $h = \sum_{k=1}^m b_k \chi_{V_k}$.  Thus $h \in Z$, and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and $Z$ is closed, we have $g \in Z$ also.